# Call a smart contract ink! as a argument of another smart contract

Tags: ink, smart-contract, cross-contract-call

I have a question about ink!. Is it possible from a smart contract A to manage the transfer of tokens of contract B IF contract B will be deployed later ?

I want a user to call a function of smart contract A (deployed and that we can't modity), put as argument the hash of  contract B and make the transfer of tokens of the contract B (from the smart contract A). And this without put `use smartcontractB` in the smartcontract A.

Comment: From my understanding you want to call `contract A` which takes as argument another `contract B`. `Contract A` will then transfer its tokens to `contract B`. What kind of token do you want to transfer?

Comment: Yes, you understood correctly ! It could be ERC20 but aswell erc721 and erc 1155 ! I want it rather wide ! Does it makes sense ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes this is possible.

When instantiating a smart contract it gets an account id, just like a user has an account id. This means that transfering tokens to/from smart contracts works the same.

Therefore, e.g. for the ERC20 contract, you can call [`fn transfer`](https://github.com/paritytech/ink-examples/blob/ed91979c0c2442370ba2d204b3857ee62dc7dc03/erc20/lib.rs#L130) with parameter `to` the account id of `contract B`.

I'm not sure if you still need `contract A` with this knowledge. But if you do, you can do something similar like:

```
        fn transfer_from_contract_a(&self, to: AccountId, value: Balance) {
            build_call::<DefaultEnvironment>()
                .call(self.erc20_contract)
                .gas_limit(0)
                .transferred_value(0)
                .call_flags(CallFlags::default().set_tail_call(true))
                .exec_input(
                    ExecutionInput::new(Selector::new(ink::selector_bytes!("transfer")))
                        .push_arg(caller),
                        .push_arg(value),
                )
                .returns::<()>()
                .try_invoke();
             .unreachable!("set_tail_call = true");
```

In this example the erc20 contract that it interacts with is stored in `contract A`. This can, however, be given as an argument as well:

```
        fn transfer_from_contract_a(&self, to: AccountId, value: Balance, erc20_as_argument: AccountId) {
            build_call::<DefaultEnvironment>()
                .call(erc20_as_argument)
                ...
        }
```

Comment: Thanks you very Daan ! It is really clear, I will implement that ! I appreciated your time :)